# Forming a quadratic equation with the given roots

Tags: quadratics

**Question**: If $\frac{p^2}{q}$ and $\frac{q^2}{p}$ are the roots of the equation $2x^2+7x-4=0$, find the equation whose roots are $p$ and $q$($p+q$ is real).

**My attempt**: The required equation is $x^2-(p+q)x+pq$

$(\frac{p^2}{q})(\frac{q^2}{p})=\frac{-4}{2}$

$pq=-2$

$\frac{p^2}{q}+\frac{q^2}{p}=\frac{-7}{2}$

$\frac{p^3+q^3}{pq}=\frac{-7}{2}$

$p^3+q^3=7$

$(p+q)^3-3pq(p+q)=7$

$(p+q)^3+6(p+q)=7$

**My problem**:I am unable to solve this equation. I think this one is a cubic equation and i do not know how to solve them. Moreover it is not in our syllabus so i there there must be another approach to find $p+q$

Comment: Let $x=p+q$ ... $x^3+6x+7=0$ This might factorise ?

Comment: Why dont you solve the quadratic it has very simple roots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{p^2}{q}+\frac{q^2}{p}=-\frac{7}{2}$$ and $pq=-2$.

Thus, $$p^3+q^3=7$$ or
$$(p+q)((p+q)^2+6)=7$$ or
$$(p+q)^3+6(p+q)-7=0,$$
which gives $p+q=1$ and we get the answer:
$$x^2-x-2=0.$$

Comment: How is $p+q=1$?

Comment: @MrAP Because $(p+q)^3+6(p+q)-7=(p+q-1)\left(\left(p+q+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2+6\frac{3}{4}\right),$ which gives $p+q=1$.

Comment: Whoa! That must be some serious factorization. Could you please explain  briefly how you did that.

Comment: @MrAP Yes, of course! $(p+q)^3+6(p+q)-7=(p+q)^3-(p+q)+7(p+q)-7=(p+q-1)((p+q)(p+a+1)+7)=(p+q-1)\left((p+q)^2+(p+q)+\frac{1}{4}+6\frac{3}{4}\right)=(p+q-1)\left(\left(p+q+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2+6\frac{3}{4}\right)$.

Comment: Oh! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

Hint. You are on the right track. Note that
$$ x^3+6x-7=(x-1)(x^2+x+7).$$

Comment: Can you please explain how you factorized the L.H.S?

Comment: @MrAP Note that $1$ is a solution, then divide $x^3+6x-7$ by $x-1$.

Comment: Do you have a general method to factorize this? I don't feel good about using hit and trial method to find a factor of the L.H.S.

Comment: Without knowing any explicit solution you have to use a general formula https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#General_formula